# Pundit, the record has no my model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

i have a model `CustomerProfile`, with a column `i24wholesaleid`
In my Pundit policy `CustomerProfilePolicy`. i wanted to add some authorization logic to the show method so:

```
 def show?
      if ((user.wholesale? and record.i24wholesaleid == user.customer_profile_id)) ...
```

but i receive a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `i24wholesaleid' for #<Class:0x007f30ce23d600>
```

and i don't understand  why record is a generic class, it should be an instance of my model class, isn't it? 
The policy is just extending the default ApplicationPolicy created by Pundit.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you said: Your column name is `i24customerid`, but you are trying to call `i24wholesaleid`. This is the reason that you are getting `undefined method 'i24wholesaleid' for #<Class:0x007f30ce23d600>`

Comment: sorry a mistake the name of the column is `i24wholesaleid`, i correct the question. the question is why record is not an instance of CustomerProfile